# In Windows CSP, is it better to get secure random numbers as one large array or several smaller ones?

Tags: random

I need to generate several random bytes arrays in one time for different purposes. What way would be preferred:

1. Generate one large random bytes array in single API call and then split by chunks for each purpose. Chunks will not intersect, simply take `[0..n)` for first purpose, `[n..n+m)` for second one and so on, where `n`, `m` - number of bytes for each corresponding purposes.
2. Generate random array for each purpose in separate API calls.

Is there any real difference between these two approaches?

Each array would be generated using crypto API. In my particular case I work with Windows CSP using [RNGCryptoServiceProvider](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.rngcryptoserviceprovider(v=vs.110).aspx).

I understand that in theory with the very perfect PRNG somewhere in the better world there would be no difference. But I'm looking for answer for my particular case with Windows CSP. If it's matter - app will work on windows server 2012. Everything is default, no any custom CSP installed.

Comment: I've updated the title to contain the essence of your question so folks who know the answer are more likely to click.

Comment: As you say there *should* be no practical difference. In UNIX, that is what is assumed when reading from `/dev/urandom`.